# WPF ComboBox will not trigger an event on initializing

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I have the following situation:
1. I have Window Load event - which gets the SourceItems for a ComboBox
2. ComboBox have EventTrigger for Selection Changed and the following XAML:

```
    <ComboBox x:Name="uxEnvironmentsComboBox" 
         ItemsSource="{Binding Environments}" Width="90" Margin="0,10,160,0" 
         HorizontalAlignment="Right"  
         VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
         HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
         IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" SelectedIndex="0">
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectEnvironment}"
                                                   CommandParameter="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ComboBox}}"/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </ComboBox>
```

Everything works, the Window Load properly, the List is populated in the ComboBox, but when the default selection is made my `<i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">`  does not trigger and the rest of the application configuration is not triggered unless I make a manual selection change ?!

Comment: what do u mean, "unless u make a manual selection change?" so you make a change and the event fires... when doesn't it fire

Comment: You'll need to post your `ViewModel` or code behind as well as your code for setting the `DataContext` for anyone to be able to assist you further.  The most common issue is usually not setting the `DataContext` properly

Comment: @JohnChris, the SourceList loads successfully, the field is being populated, but the command will not execute on startup (even tho i see the value is there). By manual selection I mean I click on the ComboBox and make any selection by myself, then the action triggers

Comment: Can you Bind the `SelectedItem` in your  `ComboBox` first and then try if it triggers SelectionChanged event.

Comment: I am new to XAML and WPF, could you please elaborate how i could do that ?

Comment: `<ComboBox x:Name="uxEnvironmentsComboBox"` **`SelectedItem="Binding propertyOnYourVM"`** `ItemsSource="{Binding Environments}" Width="90" Margin="0,10,160,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" .../>`

Comment: No, it didnt work. What i tried now is to add save EventTrigger but for "Loaded" and it worked!. Would that be considered as dirty hack ? 
`<i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectEnvironment}"
                                               CommandParameter="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ComboBox}}"/>
                    </i:EventTrigger> `

Comment: `<i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectEnvironment}"` is `SelectEnvironment` a command which has implemented the `ICommand` interface?

Answer (score 0):

`SelectEnvironment` should be a property that you bind to:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="uxEnvironmentsComboBox" 
         ItemsSource="{Binding Environments}" Width="90" Margin="0,10,160,0" 
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectEnvironment}"
         HorizontalAlignment="Right"  
         VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
         HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
         IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" SelectedIndex="0">
</ComboBox>
```

You can invoke any command in the setter of this property if you want to:

```
private Environment _selectEnvironment;
public Environment SelectEnvironment
{
    get { return _selectEnvironment; }
    set
    {
        _selectEnvironment = value;
        //invoke command
        YourCommand.Execute(_selectedEnvironment);
    }
}
```

And if you want to invoke the command or set the property initially, you could for example do this in the constructor of the view model. You don't need to use an `InvokeCommandAction`.

Comment: I cant directly bind to it, as I have two ComboBoxes, the second one depends on the first and they both form the environment configuration. I even have to add a third one to be honest. List<Environments> is different from the SelectedEnvironment object... Sorry I cannot post the full code here...

Comment: Use two or three different source properties then. After all, if you have three ComboBoxes you also have three selected values.